# how to save image with format name of image + suffix in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image

I am new to Android, Eclipse and Java. I am still developing application that pick image from album, store it in bitmap with BitmapFactory, process the bitmap, and save the processed value to the new image file.
The format of name that I want is nameoforiginalimage + _embed + .png

This is my code:
First, I initialize variable that I need :

```
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
private Bitmap sourceBitmap;
private String picturePath;
```

Second, I call album via intent :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_embed);

    final Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_PICK);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadImage);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg) {
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*.png");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}
```

Third, I put the image that I pick to the Bitmap via onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri photoUri = data.getData();

    switch(requestCode) {

    case(PICK_IMAGE) :
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (photoUri != null) {
                try {
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, null, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int indexColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                    picturePath = cursor.getString(indexColumn);

                    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    opt.inDither = false;
                    opt.inScaled = false;
                    opt.inDensity = 0;
                    opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    opt.inPurgeable = false;
                    opt.inSampleSize = 1;
                    opt.inScreenDensity = 0;
                    opt.inTargetDensity = 0;

                    sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                    ImageView hostImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewHost);
                    hostImageView.setImageBitmap(sourceBitmap);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();}

            }
        }
        break;
}
```

Finally, the Bitmap is processed, saved to new image file, and showed to the imageView in this code :

```
Button buttonProceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProceed);
    buttonProceed.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg) {

            int maxHeight = sourceBitmap.getHeight();
            int maxWidth = sourceBitmap.getWidth();
            int density = sourceBitmap.getDensity();

            int processArray[];
            Bitmap onProcessBitmap = sourceBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            processArray = new int[maxHeight * maxWidth];
            onProcessBitmap.getPixels(processArray, 0, maxWidth, 0, 0, maxWidth, maxHeight);

            // the process going in there
            for (int i = 0; i < processArray.length; i++) {
                processArray[i] = processArray[i] / 2;
            }

            onProcessBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            onProcessBitmap.setDensity(density);
            int masterIndex = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < maxHeight; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < maxWidth; i++) {
                    onProcessBitmap.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(0xFF, 
                            processArray[masterIndex] >> 16 & 0xFF, 
                            processArray[masterIndex] >> 8 & 0xFF, 
                            processArray[masterIndex++] & 0xFF));
                }
            }

            //saving sequence going in there
            Uri result = null;
            String sdcardState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            String destPath = null;
            int indexSeparator = picturePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
            int indexPoint = picturePath.lastIndexOf(".");

            if (indexPoint < 1){
                indexPoint = picturePath.length();
            }

            String fileNameDest = picturePath.substring(indexSeparator + 1, indexPoint);
            fileNameDest += "_embed";

            if (sdcardState.contentEquals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                destPath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + fileNameDest + ".png";
            }

            OutputStream fileOut = null;
            try {
                fileOut = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
                onProcessBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOut);
                result = Uri.parse("file://" + destPath);
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
                fileOut.flush();
                fileOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ImageView resultImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resultImageView);
            resultImageView.setImageBitmap(onProcessBitmap);

        }
    });
}
```

So far, I'm succesful to save it to new image file, but the image file name is saved as "_embed.png", not as theNameOfOriginalImage_embed.png.

Please, someone help me, what wrong in my code?

(for additional information, if it can help solve the problem. I developing this with
minimum required SDK = API 8 2.2 Froyo
target SDK & Compile = API 17 4.2 Jelly Bean)

Regards!

Comment: what `photoUri` or `picturePath` contain? maybe there you can find original file name to use.

Comment: Maybe something wrong in `String fileNameDest = picturePath.substring(indexSeparator + 1, indexPoint);
            fileNameDest = picturePath + "_embed";` Try to replace `picturePath` for `fileNameDest` in the second line.

Comment: picturePath contain the path of image stored down to the filename, but,
it's my bad, I'm unaware that i just change the value of fileNameDest to _embed instead of adding the value of fileNameDest (which contain originalFileName) with _embed 

So, thanks to @Long for giving me a clue, I forgot to add "+" sign before "=" in fileNameDest like this :
 `fileNameDest += "_embed";` 

Now, the code is working fine, thanks for helping me
Regards!